# Find long (>255) filenames

Tags: delphi, find, filenames, long-integer

There are some folder with more than 100 files on it.
But all files and folders names broken with wrong encoding names (UTF->ANSI).

```
"C:\...\Р“РѕСЃРґР°С‡Р°-Р›РµС‡РµР±РЅРё РєРѕСЂРїСѓСЃ\РІРµСЂС‚РѕР»РµС‚РєР°\Р“РѕСЃРґР°С‡Р°-Р›РµС‡РµР±РЅРё РєРѕСЂРїСѓСЃ\Р“РѕСЃРґР°С‡Р°-Р›РµС‡РµР±РЅРё РєРѕСЂРїСѓСЃ\РІРµСЂС‚РѕР»РµС‚РєР°\Р“РѕСЃРґР°С‡Р°-Р›РµС‡РµР±РЅРё РєРѕСЂРїСѓСЃ\РІРµСЂС‚РѕР»РµС‚РєР°\Р“РѕСЃРґР°С‡Р°-Р›РµС‡РµР±РЅРё РєРѕСЂРїСѓСЃ\Р“РѕСЃРґР°С‡Р°-Р›РµС‡РµР±РЅРё РєРѕСЂРїСѓСЃ\Р“РѕСЃРґР°С‡Р°-Р›РµС‡РµР±РЅРё РєРѕСЂРїСѓСЃ\РІРµСЂС‚РѕР»РµС‚РєР°\Р“РѕСЃРґР°С‡Р°-Р›РµС‡РµР±РЅРё РєРѕСЂРїСѓСЃ\Р“РѕСЃРґР°С‡Р°-Р›РµС‡РµР±РЅРё РєРѕСЂРїСѓСЃ\РІРµСЂС‚РѕР»РµС‚РєР°\Р“РѕСЃРґР°С‡Р°-Р›РµС‡РµР±РЅРё РєРѕСЂРїСѓСЃ\..."
```

Regular function `Utf8ToAnsi` finxing it, but `FindFirst` can't search folders with names longer than 255 symbols.

It gaves me only 70/100 files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FindFirst wraps the Win32 API function [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx), and the Unicode version of that function can search paths up to 32,767 characters long if you prepend `\\?\` to the path you're passing in, like `\\?\C:\Folder\Folder\*`.

Since Delphi 2009 and newer call the Unicode functions for you, you can just use FindFirst and co there.  For Delphi 2007 and earlier (ANSI versions), you'll need to call `FindFirstFile/FindNextFile/FindClose` from `Windows.pas` directly.  For more information check the [Naming a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx) section of the platform SDK.

Do note that using `\\?\` disables various bits of path processing though, so make sure it's a fully qualified path without any '.' or '..' entries.  You can use the same trick to open file streams, rename, or copy files with longer paths.

The shell (Explorer) doesn't support this though, so you still need to limit those to at most MAX_PATH characters for things like `SHFileOperation` (to delete to the recycle bin) or `ShellExecute`.  In many cases you can work around the problem by passing in the DOS 8.3 names instead of the long ones.  FindFirst's TSearchRec doesn't expose the short names, but FindFirstFile's `TWin32FindData` structure does as `cAlternateFileName`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the current directory ([`ChDir`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.ChDir)) to the deepest one you know about, and then pass a *relative path* to `FindFirst` or `FindFirstFile`.

No path component in that file name is longer than MAX_PATH characters, so you should be able to work your way into the directories one step at a time.

Beware that multithreaded programs may be sensitive to changes in the current directory since a process has only one current directory shared by all the threads.